# Chain arithmetic operators in dplyr with %>% pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, piping, magrittr

I would like to understand why, in the the `dplyr` or `magrittr` package, and more specifically the chaining function `%>%` has some trouble with the basic operators `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`

Chaining takes the output of previous statement and feeds it as first argument of the next:

```
1:10 %>% sum
# [55]
```

Thus how come this doesn't work

```
1:10 %>%  *2 %>% sum
1:10 %>% .*2 %>% sum
```

I also found that the following syntax works for adding/substracting, but not multiply or divide. why so?

```
1:10 %>% +(2) # works OK
1:10 %>% *(2) # nope...
```

So should I write an anonymous function even to do a `*2` operation on my data.frame?

```
1:10 %>% (function(x) x*2) %>% sum
```

Thanks, I couldn't find the answer in other SO questions.

Comment: You want to use the `magrittr` package here instead of dplyr. dplyr is only for working with data.frames while the pipe operator (`%>%`) is originally from magrittr.

Comment: Just add them normally?

Comment: Explanation of this behaviour: plus and minus only work here because the parser sees them as unary plus and minus operators, as in `-2`. So its valid syntax. So it parses okay here, and then magrittr gets to work mangling the evaluation into a binary `"-"(x, 2)` expression. There's no unary '*' or '/' function, so those ops fail. Once quoted, they become valid syntax again and the corresponding function is gotten.

Comment: Eventually I add that this way of doing also works for test operators such as '>', '=='.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Surround the operators with backticks or quotes, and things should work as expected:

```
1:10 %>%  `*`(2) %>% sum
# [1] 110

1:10 %>%  `/`(2) %>% sum
# [1] 27.5
```

Comment: Better to use backticks to quote, because it more clearly distinguishes between non-syntactic function names and strings. (The fact that `"+"(1, 3)` works is, in my opinion, a historical artefact.

Answer (score 50):

Or use the `Aliases` in `magrittr` package, e.g.:

```
1:10 %>% multiply_by(2)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20

1:10 %>% add(2)
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

The `Aliases` include 'words' for boolean operators, extract/replace, and arithmetic operators

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd share the `magrittr` documentation so you could see all of your options!

Currently implemented aliases are...

```
extract `[`
extract2    `[[`
inset   `[<-`
inset2  `[[<-`
use_series  `$`
add `+`
subtract    `-`
multiply_by `*`
raise_to_power  `^`
multiply_by_matrix  `%*%`
divide_by   `/`
divide_by_int   `%/%`
mod `%%`
is_in   `%in%`
and `&`
or  `|`
equals  `==`
is_greater_than `>`
is_weakly_greater_than  `>=`
is_less_than    `<`
is_weakly_less_than `<=`
not (`n'est pas`)   `!`
set_colnames    `colnames<-`
set_rownames    `rownames<-`
set_names   `names<-`
set_class   `class<-`
set_attributes  `attributes<-`
set_attr    `attr<-`
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer above, it is handy to use `Aliases` in `magrittr` package, e.g.:

**magrittr's pipeable operator replacements**

| operator | functional alternative |
| --- | --- |
| x * y | `x %>% multiply_by(y)` |
| x ^ y | `x %>% raise_to_power(y)` |
| x[y] | `x %>% extract(y)` |