# renaming columns to Y X1 X2 X3 X4 .. XN

Tags: r

I have some data such as:

```
data(iris)
```

I want to rename the columns such that `Species` is the `Y` variable and *all* other variables are the predictors.

What I have current doesn't give me the result I am looking for.

```
iris %>%
  select(Species, everything()) %>% # move the Y variable to the "front"
  rename(Y = 1) %>%
  rename_at(vars(2:ncol(.)), ~ paste("X", seq(2:ncol(.)), sep = ""))
```

Expected output would be colnames:

`Y, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5... XN`

Comment: `select(iris, Species, everything()) %>% setNames(c("Y", paste0("X", seq_along(colnames(.))[-1]-1)))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use %>% with replacement functions like colnames()<-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100780/use-with-replacement-functions-like-colnames)

Comment: @divibisan that post doesn't deal with creating the names dynamically

Comment: But the asker seems to know how to create the names dynamically – that part of their code works

Answer (score 4):

#### What went wrong

The mistake in your code is that it assumes the second `.` (in the anonymous function) is a **tibble**, when in fact it's really a **character** vector.  Hence, `ncol(.)` is inappropriate, and instead should be `length(.)`. Also, no need for `seq()` and given the output you requested, it should start from 1. In the end, you would have been fine with:

```
iris %>%
  select(Species, everything()) %>%
  rename(Y = 1) %>%
  rename_at(vars(2:ncol(.)), ~ paste("X", 1:length(.), sep = ""))
```

The other answers provide alternative ways of expressing this operation. A possibly cleaner version would be

```
iris %>%
  select(Species, everything()) %>%
  rename(Y = 1) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_c("X", seq_along(.)), -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm rearranging your steps to avoid having to do any subsetting in creating the names. Instead, give the first column the name `X0` knowing you're going to change it to `Y`.

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  select(Species, everything()) %>% 
  setNames(paste0("X", seq_along(.) - 1)) %>%
  rename(Y = 1) %>%
  head()
#>        Y  X1  X2  X3  X4
#> 1 setosa 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
#> 2 setosa 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2
#> 3 setosa 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
#> 4 setosa 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
#> 5 setosa 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2
#> 6 setosa 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `colnames` directly instead of using the sometimes finicky `rename` functions:

```
iris %>%
    select(Species, everything()) %>% # move the Y variable to the "front"
    `colnames<-`(c('Y', paste("X", seq(2:ncol(.)), sep = ""))) %>%
    head

       Y  X1  X2  X3  X4
1 setosa 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
2 setosa 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2
3 setosa 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
4 setosa 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
5 setosa 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2
6 setosa 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4
```

This question explains why `` `colnames<-` `` works as a function in the pipe:
[use %>% with replacement functions like colnames()<-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100780/use-with-replacement-functions-like-colnames)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with base r functions:

```
colnames(iris) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "Y") # rename columns
iris[,c(5,1,2,3,4)] # reorder 

            Y  X1  X2  X3  X4
 #  1  setosa 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
 #  2  setosa 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2
 #  3  setosa 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
 #  4  setosa 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
 #  5  setosa 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2
```