# How to rename column names containing "(N)"?

Tags: r, stringr

I'd like to remove the "(N)" from the column names.

Example data:

```
df <- tibble(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
   `id (N)` = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  `Number (N)` = c(3, 1, 2, 8)
)
```

I got so far, but don't know how to figure out the rest of regex

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(stringr::str_replace, 
              pattern = "[//(],N//)]", replacement = "")
```

But the n from the "number (N)" is gone.

```
    name    id N)   umber (N)
1   A   1   3
2   B   2   1
3   C   3   2
4   D   4   8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner: `rename_with(df, ~str_remove_all(., ' \\(N\\)'))`

or `dplyr` only: `rename_with(df, ~sub(' \\(N\\)', '', .))`

We could use the `rename_with` function from `dplyr` package and apply a function (in this case `str_remove` from `stringr` package).

And then use `\\` to escape `(`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  rename_with(~str_remove_all(., ' \\(N\\)'))
```

```
  name     id Number
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1      3
2 B         2      1
3 C         3      2
4 D         4      8
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  `id (N)` = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  `Number (N)` = c(3, 1, 2, 8)
)

df %>% names %>% str_remove("\\s*\\(N\\)\\s*") %>% set_names(df,.)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   name     id Number
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 A         1      3
#> 2 B         2      1
#> 3 C         3      2
#> 4 D         4      8
```

Comment: This looks nice, but is there a one line option?

Comment: Please, see my just edited solution, @TyperWriter. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try

```
setNames(df, gsub("\\s\\(.*\\)", "", names(df)))
```

which gives

```
  name     id Number
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1      3
2 B         2      1
3 C         3      2
4 D         4      8
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is

```
colnames(df) <- gsub(" \\(N\\)", "", colnames(df))
```

Comment: Could this be used in a %>% workflow?

Comment: @TyperWriter Yes, see [use `%>%` with replacement functions like `colnames()<-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100780/use-with-replacement-functions-like-colnames/28100903#28100903)