# How to do multiplication with magrittr pipes

Tags: r, magrittr

A traditional way of making a table in R:

```
data(mtcars)

round(100*prop.table(xtabs(~ gear + cyl, data = mtcars), 1), 2)
```

returns

```
   cyl
gear     4     6     8
  3  6.67 13.33 80.00
  4 66.67 33.33  0.00
  5 40.00 20.00 40.00
```

To replicate this using the `magrittr` pipes, I've tried:

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>%
 xtabs(~ gear + cyl, data = .) %>%
 prop.table(., 1)
```

which works great up to this point

```
    cyl
gear          4          6          8
   3 0.06666667 0.13333333 0.80000000
   4 0.66666667 0.33333333 0.00000000
   5 0.40000000 0.20000000 0.40000000
```

but any attempt to perform the next part, wherein I convert proportions to percentages, and then round, results in an error. For instance:

```
mtcars %>%
  xtabs(~ gear + cyl, data = .) %>%
  100*prop.table(., 1)
```

and

```
mtcars %>%
  xtabs(~ gear + cyl, data = .) %>%
  prop.table(., 1) %>%
  100 * .
```

all result in an error. What am I missing?

Comment: In your example, the margin was for rows, In the `magrittr`, you are using `columns`.  `mtcars %>% xtabs(~gear+cyl, data=.) %>% prop.table(.,1) %>% multiply_by(100) %>% round(., 2)`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27364575/3871924

Comment: @akrun--thanks for the catch, corrected above.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to put `*` in quotes - `"*"()`, also use `1` as your argument in `prop.table` to match the example.

```
mtcars %>%
  xtabs(~ gear + cyl, data = .) %>%
  prop.table(., 1) %>%
  "*"(100 ) %>% round(.,2)
```

Comment: @john, is there any difference between using quotes("") and using backticks(``) ?

Comment: @Ashrith - I don't think so, both should work