# Write own / custom pipe operator

Tags: r, pipe

I would like to write a custom pipe operator where the used **operator name is open**. It could be e.g. `%>%`, `%|%`, `:=`, ... Maybe it needs to be chosen depending on the needed *operator precedence* like explained in [Same function but using for it the name %>% causes a different result compared when using the name :=](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76155741/10488504).

The used **placeholder name is open** but `.` or `_` are common and it needs to be **placed explicitly** (no automatically placement as first argument).

The **evaluation environment is open**. But in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76155435/10488504) it looks like that using the user environment should be avoided.

It should be able to **keep the value in the user environment** in case it has the same name as the placeholder.

```
1 %>% identity(.)
#[1] 1
.
#Error: object '.' not found

. <- 2
1 %>% identity(.)
#[1] 1
.
#[1] 2
```

It should be able to **update values in the user environment** including the name of the placeholder.

```
1 %>% assign("x", .)
x
#[1] 1

"x" %>% assign(., 2)
x
#[1] 2

1 %>% assign(".", .)
.
#[1] 1

"." %>% assign(., 2)
.
#[1] 2

x <- 1 %>% {names(.) <- "foo"; .}
x
#foo 
#  1
```

It should **evaluate from left to right**.

```
1 %>% . + 2 %>% . * 3
#[1] 9
```

---

The shortest way I know defining a pipe operator, which is setting `.` to the value of the lhs in a new environment and evaluates rhs in it, is:

```
`:=` <- function(lhs, rhs) eval(substitute(rhs), list(. = lhs))
```

But here values in the calling environment could not be created or changed.

So another try is assigning lhs to the placeholder `.` in the calling environment and evaluate the rhs in the calling environment.

```
`:=` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  assign(".", lhs, envir=parent.frame())
  eval.parent(substitute(rhs))
}
```

Here already most things work but it creates or overwrites the variable . in the calling scope.

So adding to remove the placeholder on exit:

```
`:=` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  on.exit(if(exists(".", parent.frame())) rm(., envir = parent.frame()))
  assign(".", lhs, envir=parent.frame())
  eval.parent(substitute(rhs))
}
```

Now is only the problem that `.` will be removed from calling environment in case it was already there.

So check if `.` is already there store it and reinsert it on exit in case lhs was not modified.

```
`:=` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  e <- exists(".", parent.frame(), inherits = FALSE)
  . <- get0(".", envir = parent.frame(), inherits = FALSE)
  assign(".", lhs, envir=parent.frame())
  on.exit(if(identical(lhs, get0(".", envir = parent.frame(), inherits = FALSE))) {
            if(e) {
              assign(".", ., envir=parent.frame())
            } else {
              if(exists(".", parent.frame())) rm(., envir = parent.frame())
            }
          })
  eval(substitute(rhs), parent.frame())
}
```

But it fails when trying:

```
. <- 0
1 := assign(".", .)
.
#[1] 0
```

The following gives the expected result but I'm not sure if it really evaluates from left to right.

```
1 := . + 2 := . * 3
#[1] 9
```

Comment: Try [this](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/9USvFSLrKpQ)

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising. But `1 := assign(".", .)` or `"." := assign(., 2)` do not give the expected result. Anyway can you post an answer of this solution?

Comment: I think the `1 := assign(".", .)` and `x <- 1 := {names(.) <- "foo"; .}` cases might be inconsistent. You want `.` to mean 2 things at the same time in the same environment, What would `x <- 1 := {. <- .; .}` do ? We could special case `assign()`just to satisfy your tests but I'm not sure if that would satisfy you

Comment: I have a solution that works for all but `x <- 1 := {names(.) <- "foo"; .}` where `.` is a self destructing active binding, that can be used only once by definition.

Comment: I found `1 := {names(.) <- "foo"; .}` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76155435/10488504 with *We can fix this with a different implementation, which does not replace . with the LHS but rather injects a definition of . into the environment where the RHS is evaluated:*

Comment: but you want this environment where RHS is to be evaluated to be the caller env, so `1 %>% assign("x", .)` works, and if you define your own `.`  there you necessarily lose the original one, you can back it up and set it back after, but not use both at the same time in your expression, which `1 := assign(".", .)` attempts to do.

Comment: I don't care if the RHS is evaluated in the caller env. But yes, it would be fine if `1 %>% assign("x", .)` works, and in this case i have expected that the original `.` is replaced by the new one. If all is not possible at the same time, maybe an improved way of the current method in the question would also be fine.

Comment: I think if we want `assign(".", .)` to overwrite the old dot but `names(.) <- "foo"` to overwrite the new dot we need `<-` and `assign()` to be different things. environment play alone won't be enough. We might achieve this by overriding `assign()` locally or temporarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one means you need a precedence under arithmetic ops

```
1 %>% . + 2 %>% . * 3
```

This dismisses any `%>%` op, `:=` is not a bad choice, we might also use `?`, let's go with `:=`.

`assign()` and `<-` normally do the same thing by default. But your examples imply otherwise :

You would like `assign(".", "foo")` to overwrite the old dot but `names(.) <- "foo"` (and presumably `. <- "foo"`) to override the new dot and not affect the old one.

I believe the only way to achieve this is to special case `assign()`, I do it below and your tests are satisfied.

With this solution we evaluate the expression in a child environment of the caller which inherits from all values except for the dot which is in this child env, and a modified assign functions that assigns in the caller when environment args are not provided.

```r
`:=` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  pf <- parent.frame()
  rhs_call <- substitute(rhs)
  assign2 <- function (x, value, pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), inherits = FALSE, 
                       immediate = TRUE) {
    if (missing(pos) && missing(envir)) envir <- pf
    assign(x, value, envir = envir, inherits = inherits, immediate = immediate)
  }
  eval(rhs_call, envir = list(. = lhs, assign = assign2), enclos = pf)
}

1 := identity(.)
#> [1] 1
.
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '.' not found

. <- 2
1 := identity(.)
#> [1] 1
.
#> [1] 2

1 := assign("x", .)
x
#> [1] 1

"x" := assign(., 2)
x
#> [1] 2

1 := assign(".", .)
.
#> [1] 1

"." := assign(., 2)
.
#> [1] 2

x <- 1 := {names(.) <- "foo"; .}
x
#> foo 
#>   1

1 := . + 2 := . * 3
#> [1] 9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Jishan Shaikh in the comments.

```
`:=` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  env <- parent.frame()
  
  # Save the value of the placeholder variable if it exists
  if (exists(".", envir = env, inherits = TRUE)) {
    dot_value <- get0(".", envir = env, inherits = TRUE)
  } else {
    dot_value <- NULL
  }
  
  # Assign the new value to the placeholder variable
  assign(".", lhs, envir = env)
  
  # Evaluate the right-hand side expression
  rhs_value <- eval(substitute(rhs), env)
  
  # Restore the value of the placeholder variable
  if (!is.null(dot_value)) {
    assign(".", dot_value, envir = env)
  } else {
    rm(".", envir = env)
  }
  
  # Return the value of the right-hand side expression
  return(rhs_value)
}
```

Tests

```
1 := identity(.)
#> [1] 1
.
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '.' not found

. <- 2
1 := identity(.)
#> [1] 1
.
#> [1] 2

1 := assign("x", .)
x
#> [1] 1

"x" := assign(., 2)
x
#> [1] 2

1 := assign(".", .)
.
#> [1] 2  #!

"." := assign(., 3)
.
#> [1] 2  #!

x <- 1 := {names(.) <- "foo"; .}
x
#> foo 
#>   1

1 := . + 2 := . * 3
#> [1] 9
```